# Click on Notification then finish TimerTask?

Tags: android, timer, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am creating `Notification` in a `Activity`(For example `text.class`) and when active that and i `Click on it` , it return me in that page(`text.class`) in this page i have a `TimerTask` and i need that when `Click on that Notification Reset page` or `Finish() the TimerTask`  .

How I can do it ?

I thought that when I `click on notification` the `reset page` and `finish TimerTask`.

This is my `Notification` :

```
NotificationManager nman;
nman=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Long when=System.currentTimeMillis();
Notification n;
n=new Notification(R.drawable.chat_logo,"",when);
Context context=getApplicationContext();
String Title=G.context.getResources().getString(R.string.StatusM);
String Text=G.context.getResources().getString(R.string.Statusms);
Intent notifintent=new Intent(context,ConversationPage.class);
PendingIntent pending;
pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notifintent,android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
n.setLatestEventInfo(context, Title, Text, pending);
n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
nman.notify(0,n);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag to the `notifintent` deliver intent to running Activity with extra key which indicate is intent from `Notification`? if yes then cancel already running  `TimerTask` in `onNewIntent` :

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
        if(extras.containsKey("isfromnotification"))
        {
           //cancel TimerTask here
        }
    }
```